# Z-index settings not working, dropdown menu should be behind file button

Tags: html, css

I left out some HTML & CSS I didn't think was important but its all in the fiddle. I'd like the menubar to be behind the file button, see expected and actual result images at bottom.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/danielyaa5/74g987qn/27/)

### HTML

```
<div class="menubar">

    <div class="dropdown" id="file-btn">
      <button href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">File <span class="caret"></span></button>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
        <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
        <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
        <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
        <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

### CSS

```
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

.analysis {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100%;
}


/* MENUBAR */

.menubar {
  height: 35px;
  font-size: 12px;
  background-color: #eee;
  border: hsl(0, 0%, 75%) solid 1px;
  border-right: none;
  border-left: none;
  position: relative;
}

/* VIEWS-CTRLS-CNTNR */

#view-ctrls-cntnr {
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

#view-ctrls-cntnr button {
  font-size: inherit;
}


/*view-ctrls-cntnr */

/* FILE-BTN */

#file-btn {
  margin-left: 34px;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 100;
}

#file-btn button {
  line-height: 30px;
  color: black;
  background-color: transparent;
  border: none;
}

#file-btn button:focus {
  background-color: white;
}

#file-btn:hover {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.0392157);
}

/* FILE-DROPDOWN */

#file-btn .dropdown-menu {
  margin-top: -1px;
  z-index: 10;
  left: -34px;
  border-left: none;
  border-radius: 0;
}

/* file-btn */

/* menubar */
```

#### Expected

[image]

#### Actual

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the following styles to `#file-btn button`

```
#file-btn button {
    /*previous styles*/
    position: relative;
    z-index: 99;
}
```

Also increase the `margin-top` of your dropdown to -2 to account for the 1 px border and 1px overlap

```
#file-btn .dropdown-menu {
  margin-top: -2px;
  /*other styles*/
}
```

Updated [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/74g987qn/31/)

Answer (score 0):

The button doesn't have a `z-index` nor [stacking context](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Positioning/Understanding_z_index/The_stacking_context), you currently have z-ordered the menu itself (which is confusingly named `#menu-btn`).

```
#file-btn {
  margin-left: 34px;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100%;
}

#file-btn button {
  position: relative;
  line-height: 30px;
  color: black;
  background-color: transparent;
  border: none;
  z-index: 100;
}
```

[fixed fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/74g987qn/28/)

Answer (score 0):

The z-index property only works for positioned elements (See [here](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp)). You will therefore need to make your elements with z-index have their position be relative, absolute, or fixed. I would recomend position:relative as this will not change the positioning of your elements.